# Style the text of an Android Button disabled

Tags: android, button, styles

I want the text of a Button to keep its original color when the button is disabled, but It becomes grey transparent.
In fact I'm not able to style the text of a disable button.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use enable/disable, it will always gets grey if its disabled. Set selectable(boolean boo) on true/false instead and change the style then how you like it.

Comment: What is `selectable`? I don't understand your fix

Comment: Thats an attribute you can use instead of setEnabled(boolean boo)

Comment: This function doesn't seem to exist, do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: @johanvs `view.setSelected(true)` where `view` is a child of `android.view.View`.